# iOS - No Known class method for selector 'dataForDay:month:year'

Tags: xcode, ios8, kal

I got this error when I use [kal library](https://github.com/phaibin/Kal)  its inside KalLogic.m

> No Known class method for selector 'dataForDay:month:year'

Any suggestion to fix it

Screen shot of problem [image]

Comment: Did you import NSDate+Convenience.h ?

Comment: yes , and when i press cmd at this method it redirected to NSDate+Convenience.m

Comment: Did you add the flag "-ObjC" to the additional flags ? Did you cleaned your project after import the Kal Library ?

Comment: how can i add flag "-ObjC"  , i use xcode 6

Comment: Like in Xcode 5, Selector your project->Build Settings->Linking->Other Linker Flags

Comment: I got linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: CAn you drop the complet error message. This is not enough to help you.

Comment: whole error is  ld: file not found: /Users/uencom/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/School_Link_Version_2-dchqvqakvwsbtpdnzqenblgwfsyq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/School Link Version 2.app/School Link Version 2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Clean your derivedData from the Organizer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you import NSDate+Convenience library

```
 import NSDate+Convenience.h
```

Second add "-ObjC" to the additional flags 
[image]